# Does UDP connection take care of checksum of the packet after being sent?

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I want to send a file from a client to a server. I want to send it by breaking the file into packet size of like 1000 bytes each and send it one by one. Now, after the server receives the packet, it might get corrupted. So, should I use a header and send the checksum of the packet along with the packet and check if they match after the server receives it? or UDP has a default feature to check the checksum automatically?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol#Checksum_computation

Comment: The UDP checksum is _optional_ on IPv4, but it is _required_ on IPv6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, UDP has a checksum that automatically checks the packet. You can read about the algorithm on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol#Checksum_computation).

Many operating systems have an option that controls whether the checksum caclculation is done, and until the 1990's it was common for this to be disabled for performance reasons. I think most have it enabled these days, and it's likely that it's done automatically by many NICs.

Answer (score 0):

UDP has a 16-bit checksum, and your operating system will likely drop the packet if there is a mismatch. You can, however, set this checksum to 0 to bypass checking, and implement your own.

But if you're using UDP in the first place, you should *expect* some packets dropped or lost. This doesn't play well when transmitting files, so I would recommend you use TCP for that.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to use UDP and make a TCP-like connection manually by ACKs. So, if the OS drops the packet, the server should send it again, right? Assuming that I don't want any packet loss.

Comment: No, if push an small size object, send rapidly from server client requested which are missed parts. UDP choice for speed-up and non-block communication(like stream), why not push as a `static file`(www_style) ? @Manohar